# PayPal IPN for Reversal and Canceled_Reversal payment status

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have search a lot but I can not find the answer. I am intergrading paypal with my site and I am using ipn to get messages back to my site about transaction statuses. I have so far completed the "Complete" and "Refund" statuses. What I do when I receive a "Complete" status is that I issue a license key and when I receive a "Refund" status I revoke the corresponding license.

What I am not sure is what should I do when I receive a "Reversal" and/or "Canceled_Reversal" status. Should I revoke the license when I receive a "Reversal" status and then re-issue it again if I receive a "Canceled_Reversal" status regarding the same transaction?

Or does a "Canceled_Reversal" status can come without a corresponding "Reversal" status? Am I understating this correctly?

Thanks

Comment: You have used `php` and `mysql` tag for your question. Are they related to your question? Please explain it by showing the relevant sections of your code.

Comment: Hi my code is php and I am using mysql to implement it. That's way I have tag php and mySQL. Perhaps it was wrong. How do I remove it? Nevermind I was able to remove it my self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I revoke the license when I receive a "Reversal" status and then re-issue it again if I receive a "Canceled_Reversal" status regarding the same transaction?

Yes. More probably you should suspend it and de-suspend it, if your system has such a concept.

> Or does a "Canceled_Reversal" status can come without a corresponding "Reversal" status?

No.